# Alternative to nested for loop

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

I am working on a bash script for comparing several positions with given start position/end positions.
I have two different files (with different size):

- File 1: start and end position (tab seperated)
- File 2: single position

Bash is really slow while processing for loops and I had the idea of using python for this approach.

```
python - << EOF


posList=posString.split()
endList=endString.split()
startList=startString.split()

for j, val2  in enumerate(posList):
        for i, val1 in enumerate(startList):
                if val1 >= val2 and endList[i] <= val2:
                        print "true", val2
                else:
                        print "false", val2

EOF
```

I have **three strings** as **input** (position, start, end) and split them into **lists**. 
With the two nested loops I iterate over the bigger position file and then over the star/end file. If my conditions are fullfilled (*if pos > start and position < end*) I would like to print something.

My input files are string, whitespace seperated with numbers.

Maybe I'm absolutly on the wrong way, I hope not, but with this idea it takes too long to work with it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did I miss a concrete question here?  What do you want to know?

Comment: Oh sorry, I would like to know if you have any ideas how I can speed this process up? Is there an alternative to my nested for loopd?

Comment: Where is `posString` and `endString` coming from?  Hard to test this is the given code is incomplete and one has to derive example values first ...

Comment: I imported a bash array via the command: endString="$endJOIN" 
Sorry it is the second time that I'm write questions in a forum and so forget to hand in important informations.
The files can look like:
endJOIN="2 4 6 7 9"
startJOIN="1 3 4 4"
posJOIN="2 3 4 8"

Comment: Okay, so you would like to have output `true` for each time a _position_ is in one of the _ranges_, right?  And each time a position is not in one of the range, you'd like to have `false` printed.  And the _position_ itself along with it.  That means you have will always print _n_ × _m_ lines, is that what you want?

Comment: A more typical task would be to _find_ the positions which are in _any_ of the ranges.  But that's not your task, am I right?

Comment: If position is in the range I would like to print true and the corresponding value (val2 and maybe more but not right now). I just added the else case to see if there is something wrong, but actually I don't need the else case. So just "if in range, print true and value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start by sorting the positions and the ranges, you can save a lot of time:

```
range_sorted_list = sorted(zip(start_list, end_list))
range_sorted_iter = iter(range_sorted_list)
pos_sorted_list = sorted(pos_list)

start, end = next(range_sorted_iter)

try:        
    for pos in pos_sorted_list:
        while pos >= end:
            start, end = next(range_sorted_iter)
        if start <= pos < end:
            print "True", pos
        elif pos < start:
            print "False", pos
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

This will allow you to only go over the arrays once, instead of once for every position.

Answer (score 0):

Itertools is the way to go. The product function uses vector operations to make the execution more efficient.  [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

posList=posString.split()
endList=endString.split()
startList=startString.split()

for (j, val2),(i,val1) in product(enumerate(posList),enumerate(startList)):
       if val1 >= val2 and endList[i] <= val2:
                print "true", val2
       else:
                print "false", val2,
```